# ArcGIS Calculate Field, Python Shape Expression

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, error-999999

Using ArcGIS 10.1 and Python 2.7-
I am trying to write an expression that calculates the mid point of a line.  I've tried many different expressions, but I continue to get syntax errors.

```
#An example of one of my many failed attempts
arcpy.CalculateField_management(StreetCenterlines, "Latitude", "!SHAPE@X!")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(StreetCenterlines, "Longitude", "!SHAPE@Y!")
```

Can anyone lend a hand at how my expression should read in order to accomplish this?

The error I receive is: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Syntax error Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: What is the error you get from a full code snippet that you present?

Comment: The error I receive is:

ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Syntax error
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: !Shape!.positionAlongLine( !Shape!.length/2).firstPoint.X  Don't forget Python

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Adding "Python" seems to have fixed this method (I thought that argument was optional, guess not).  If I wanted to use this method and convert the Lat/Long coords to decimal degrees, do you know how I would do that?  
When I add the @DECIMALDEGREES conversion, I get a syntax error.
arcpy.CalculateField_management(workingBrazosCenterlines, "Lat_MidPt", "!SHAPE.CENTROID.X@DECIMALDEGREES!", "PYTHON_9.3")

ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up `data access update cursors` and `calculate field`.

Use the data access update cursor (it's faster):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (StreetCenterlines, ["Latitude", "Longitude", "SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"]) as cursor:
    for lat, long, x, y in cursor:
        row = (x, y, x, y)
        cursor.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  This method worked as well.  Looks like I need to learn the new data access methods.

If I wanted to convert these X, Y points to decimal degrees, is there a way with this method?